# How to display utf8 chinese in html with php

Tags: php, html, utf-8

I have chinese characters stored in my mysql database in utf-8, but I need to show them on a webpage that has to be output as charset=ISO-8859-1

When rendered in Latin my test string looks like this "dsfsdfsdf åšä¸€ä¸ªæµ‹è¯•"

I have tried using htmlentities in the following ways because I can't tell from the php docs if $encoding refers to the encoding of the input string or desired output string.

```
$row['admin_comment']=htmlentities( $row['admin_comment'] ,
                        ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 ,
                        'ISO-8859-1' , 
                        false  );

$row['admin_comment']=htmlentities( $row['admin_comment'] ,
                        ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 ,
                        'UTF-8' , 
                        false  );
```

But both have output string unchanged

Comment: Did you try echo utg8_decode ?

Comment: The chinese characters don't exist in ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot output chinese character in the **ISO-8859-1** charset. It's simply impossible.

You have 2 possibilities:

1. stick to **UTF-8** (recommended)
2. pick another chinese-compatible charset (**BIG5** If my memory serves me right)

Why your page MUST be rendered as **LATIN-1**? I find this requirement very strange. My suggestion is to use EVERYWHERE (from DataBase encoding to HTML rendering) the **UTF-8** charset. It will save you A LOT of pain in the future.

Comment: For some reason I had thought there were html entity codes for chinese characters but now i'm not finding it.  Its a legacy page of over 2000 lines across many files with php and html and javascript in each file, so this was my first approach.

Comment: there are a freaking lot (thousands or more) chinese characters... It's an impossible task to have an html entity for each one!

Answer (score 0):

The `htmlentities` function does not convert characters into their numeric character entities. For that you can use the [`mb_encode_numericentity`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php) function:

```
$row['admin_comment'] = mb_encode_numericentity($row['admin_comment'], 
                            array(0xFF, 0xFFFF, 0, 0xFFFF), "UTF-8");
```

You probably should look into migrating to UTF-8 though.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can set an iframe in your page to a different encoding.